# Caching autocomplete JSON responses

Tags: jquery, json, api, caching, autocomplete

Are there are any particular tricks or requirements for getting browsers to cache JSON API responses for something like autocomplete?

- we have a form, which takes a building name
- there are about 1500 building names, so we don't want to download all of these unnecessarily
- we transmit an API query after at least two characters are typed, e.g. to api.website.com/autocomplete?q=as

What do I need to do on client side so that if a user types something and then deletes, that they don't requery. e.g. they type `a-s-p-<delete>-t` how can I prevent duplicate `?q=as` queries from occurring? I had expected this to be automatic if I include a Cache-Control header but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use with jQuery autocomplete (read comments for purpose). It caches the results client-side so you don't need to deal with server/browser caching. This particular example was for a simple vendor name lookup:

```
// An obbject/map for search term/results tracking
var vendorCache = {};

// Keep track of the current AJAX request
var vendorXhr;

$('#VendorName').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        // Check if we already searched and map the existing results
        // into the proper autocomplete format
        if (request.term in vendorCache) {
            response($.map(vendorCache[request.term], function (item) {
                return { label: item.name, value: item.name, id: item.id };
            }));
            return;
        }
        // search term wasn't cached, let's get new results
        vendorXhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'path/to/vendor/controller',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                // cache the results
                vendorCache[request.term] = data;
                // if this is the same request, return the results
                if (xhr === vendorXhr) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.name, value: item.name, id: item.id };
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $('#VendorId').val((ui.item ? ui.item.id : ''));
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#VendorId').val((ui.item ? ui.item.id : ''));
    },
    minLength: 3 // require at least three characters from the user 
});
```

Basically you keep track of the search results in an object indexed by term. If you search for the same term, you get the cached results. There's some extra code for cancelling and reusing the currently running AJAX request as well.